# Stuck computing the gcd $ (n!+1,n+1)$, while computing $(n!+1,(n+1)!)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

$(n!+1,(n+1)!)$ can be rewritten as $(n!+1,(n+1)*n!)$.

I know that if $n!$ is divisible by a prime $p$ then $p$ doesn't divide n!+1.
So when I'm looking at then is $(n!+1 , n+1)$ which I can make $(n!-n,n+1)$ by 
subtracting $n+1$ from $n!+1$ and since gcd is preserved in linear combinations I 
still get the same gcd for $(n!-n,n+1)$. I then look at $n!-n = n[(n-1)!-1]$ again
if a prime $p$ divides $n$ I'll find that $p$ doesn't divide $n+1$. So I'm looking at
$((n-1)!-1,n+1)$. I've looked at the first few n's and it seems that the gcd is either
1 or n+1. But I'm stuck on how to get there from $((n-1)!-1,n+1)$.

Can anybody provide a hint as to how to proceed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Hint** $ $ Consider $\,(n+1,n!+1).\,$ If  prime $\,p\ |\ n+1\,$ and $\,p \le n\,$ then $\,p\ |\ n!\,$ so $\,p\nmid n!+1.\,$ Therefore the gcd $ = 1\,$ if $\,n+1\,$ is composite. For $\,n+1\,$ prime use Wilson's theorem.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/691979/242) for a similar problem solved using more general methods (which also apply here).

Answer (score 7):

You've done great work!

So yes, you know that the only numbers that could possible divide both sides are $n+1$ or $1$ (which I consider to be the hard part). So we ask ourselves, what is $n! + 1 \mod (n+1)$. If it's zero, solid. If not, relatively prime.

What does Wilson's Theorem say again? (I love it when we get to use Wilson's Theorem for anything, as its applications sort of rarely come up).

Answer (score 2):

Let

$gcd(n!+1,(n+1)!)=d$.\
$\therefore d/n!+1, d/(n+1)n!$.\
$\Rightarrow d/n!+1,d/n+1,d/n!$.\
$\Rightarrow d/n!+1-n!$.\
Hence we get $d/1$.
It follows that $d=1$.